# Expander Reset Arrow Direction

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have to collapse the all the rows details templates when a different one is expanded, but when this is done the arrows in the first column have some that are in the wrong direction. I am trying to cycle through the first column where the expander is and set the arrows for all, but the one being expanded to the down direction. The image shows the arrow in red being in the wrong direction.

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="40">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander Name="expanderCollumn" Expanded="Expander_Expanded_Collapsed"     Collapsed="Expander_Expanded_Collapsed">
                            </Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>


private void Expander_Expanded_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    IEnumerable<DataGridRow> rows = GetDataGridRows(datagrid);
    for (Visual vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
    if (vis is DataGridRow)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)vis;
        foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
        {                            
            if (r != row)
                r.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        break;
    } 
}
```

[image: the arrow that is circled in red is backwards.]

Comment: Sounds like this could be solved with MVVM and binding to `IsExpanded` or similar. Also, a screenshot might help readers visualize what the actual problem is.

Comment: You are changing `DetailsVisibility`, which has nothing to do with `expanderCollumn` element. Perhaps you can dive into `VisualTree` children, find `Expander` there and collapse it for other rows. Btw, that thing you are trying to implement has a name - [Accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5977068/1997232).